# Can we find a function with these properties?

Tags: functions

Can I find a function $f(\cdot)$ of the following properties?

1. $f(\cdot)$ is monotonically increasing and bijective;
2. $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$;
3. $f(0)=0$;
4. For each integer $K$ and each choices of positive real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_K$, there exists a positive real number $A$ and a positive real number $\alpha\le \frac{1}{K}$ such that:

   - $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{K}f(x_k)\le A$; and
   - $f(x_k)\ge \alpha A$ for all $k=1..K$.

Comment: For arbitrary $A$? Just take $x_1, \ldots, x_K$ and $A = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 1}^K f(x_k)$.

Comment: Not following condition $4$ .  This obviously can't hold for all choices of $\{x_i\}$ etc.  What is specified?

Comment: What does $\Bbb R_+$ mean? Surely not what I expected it to mean, if $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: It is the set of non-negative real numbers, i.e., $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,\infty)$.

Comment: What says (4)? Should there be an "exists" right before "a positive real..." ? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, there exists $A$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: (4) is not clear enough. I read it as: "For each $K$ and each choice of $x_1,\ldots,x_K$ there exist $A$ and $\alpha$ such that the two relations hold." Is this correct? Also: Should the second relation hold for each $k$?

Comment: I fixed this accordingly.

Comment: Seems like (4) is a non-property. If we get to choose $A$ and $\alpha$ after we choose $K$ and the $x_i$, then we can just choose $A=\sum$ and $\alpha$ to be sufficiently small. Perhaps it's supposed to be $\exists\alpha\,\forall K\,\forall x_i\,\exists A$ ?

Comment: But can we find a function $f$ then?

Comment: My point is, as written now, *any* strictly monotonic increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ with $f(0)=0$ will work. The condition (4) doesn't add anything. Can you give an example of a function satisfying (1,2,3) which you were hoping *wouldn't* satisfy (4)? I think (4) is now clearly written enough that we might be able to fix it with a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES.

Let $f$ be an increasing bijection satisfying points $1,2$ and $3$. We need besides $f$ satisfying the last point $4$.

Note first that $x\gt 0\iff f(x)\gt 0$. Take now an arbitrary $(K,x_1,x_2,…,x_K)\in \mathbb N*\mathbb R_+^K$.

We need to exhibit appropriate  $A$ and $\alpha$ according to the point $4$.

We can assume WLOG that $x_1\le x_2\le ….. \le x_K$ and $x_1\gt 0$ so that $$0\lt f(x_1)\le f(x_2)\le ….. \le f(x_K)$$

Take $$f(x_1)+f(x_2)+….. +f(x_K)=A$$ and $$\alpha= \min \{\frac{f(x_1)}{A}, \frac 1K\}$$
With this one has $$\alpha \le \frac 1K$$ and $$ f(x_K)\ge f(x_{(K-1)})\ge f(x_{(K-2)})\ge…..\ge f(x_1)\ge  \alpha A$$

Comment: Thank you. So any function that satisfy 1., 2. and 3. would work with the choice of $A$ and $\alpha$? I can take $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: I think this works for any bijection such that $f(0)=0$